# Collector toConcurrentMap() - What should the MergeFunction for a stream of Unique elements

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, treemap

Create map using parallel stream

I have this working code to create a map and populate using parallel stream

```
SortedMap<Double, Double> map = new TreeMap<>();

for (double i = 10d; i < 50d; i += 2d)
    map.put(i, null);
    
map.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(e -> {
    double res = bigfunction(e.getKey());
    e.setValue(100d - res); 
});
```

I'm working on reimplementing the above code in a proper way.

*Incomplete code:*

```
SortedMap<Double, Double> map = DoubleStream.iterate(10d, i -> i + 2d).limit(20)
    .parallel()
    .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
        k -> k, k -> {
            double res = bigfunction(k);
            return 100d - res;
        },
        null,
        TreeMap::new
    ));
```

- What should be the `mergeFunction` in this case
- What changes are required to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things. First, you need to box the primitive `DoubleStream` by calling [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#boxed--) in order to use it with a `Collector`. Second, you don't need `toConcurrentMap()`. It's safe to call `toMap()` on a parallel stream. Finally, the merge function will never be invoked in this scenario, because you're iterating over distinct keys, so I would go with what's simplest:

```
SortedMap<Double, Double> map = DoubleStream.iterate(10d, i -> i + 2d)
        .limit(20)
        .boxed()
        .parallel()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                i -> i, i -> 100d - bigfunction(i), (a, b) -> b, TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: At first glance I thought that the sequential stream `DoubleStream.iterate` could not possibly benefit from adding `parallel()`, but (part of my morning wasted) it does indeed apply `Collectors.toMap` across multiple threads.

Comment: It depends on the Java version, how well `DoubleStream.iterate` performs in parallel. Generally, `IntStream.range(0, 20).mapToDouble(i -> 10 + i * 2)` would be better than `DoubleStream.iterate(10d, i -> i + 2d) .limit(20)`. Note that not only `toConcurrentMap` is unnecessary, it doesn’t even work with `TreeMap` (which would be spotted by the compiler already).

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can throw from the `mergeFunction` of the collector, since you don't expect it to be used.

```
(left, right) -> {
    throw new AssertionError("Duplicate has been encountered: " + left);
}
```

If at a later point in time, someone would alter the stream source in such a way that stream data would no longer be unique, it would immediately become clear that this change goes against the initial logic. Meanwhile, a dummy merger like `(a, b) -> b` would hide the fact that data is being processed and then thrown away.

It's also worth to be aware:

- that while performing calculations with `double` your result might appear to be non-accurate because this type inherently incapable to represent precisely fractions which are not power of `2`. For that reason, some data might be lost. If your `bigfunction()` does a lot of calculations and loosing precision is not acceptable, you might consider using [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html), but keep in mind that computations would become much heavier.
- Another important thing to consider is that *collector* [`toConcurrentMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toConcurrentMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) expects a **concurrent** implementation of `Map` (credits to *@DuncG* for spotting this). Contrary to collectors optimized for single-threaded environment like `toMap()`, which would create a new instance of the container for each thread and then would merge the containers, *concurrent collectors* like `toConcurrentMap()` create **only one** container. I.e. each thread would operate with the same map, and it should be thread-safe. Therefore, `TreeMap` is not suitable for this scenario. Instead, we can use [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) which also maintains its data ordered by *key*.
- While dealing with a `ConcurrentSkipListMap` (or `TreeMap`), interface [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html) is more useful because it gives access to methods like `higherEntry()`, `higherKey()`, etc. which are not available with `SortedMap`.

That how the code might look like:

```
NavigableMap<Double, Double> map = DoubleStream.iterate(10d, i -> i + 2d)
    .limit(20)
    .parallel()
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(
        Function.identity(),
        k -> 100d - bigfunction(k),
        (left, right) -> {
            throw new AssertionError("Duplicate has been encountered: " + left);
        },
        ConcurrentSkipListMap::new
    ));
```